# syntax error : unterminated string literal

Tags: jquery, string

I have following code in jquery:

```
var user_id = "<?=$_SESSION['user_id'];?>";
var fb_mail = "<?=$_SESSION['facebook_mail'];?>";
var google_mail = "<?=$_SESSION['google_mail'];?>";
```

error in above code is `syntax error:unterminated string literal`

Can anybody help me

Comment: You have PHP inside the string. What does the `$_SESSION['user_id']` resolve to?

Comment: One of those values must be having a `"` in it. Check the generated page source (right click -> view source).

Comment: @Huey `user_id` is session

Comment: @techfoobar ok i will check it

Comment: I know it's a `$_SESSION` variable, but what is its value? Like techfoobar said, it probably has a double quote inside.

Comment: in session value is integer value

Comment: Try to check with "view page source" since php is evaluated first. This will show what is currently being assigned to your javascript variables. Post the fragment with your JavaScript vars

Comment: @alex ok i will check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all check the session whether exist or not

like that

```
 var user_id = "<? if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) { echo $_SESSION['user_id']; } ?>";
```

Finally i got solution

Thanks for help me resolve task